# dict.get(None) on a dict with None value takes default arg

Tags: python

I'm trying to generalize this scenario:

```
def func(t):
    # code which doesn't accept None's

def foo(a):
    if a in ('', None):
        return None
    return func(a)

def foo_b(a):
    if a in ('', None):
        return None
    elif a == 'b'
         return 0
    return func(a)
```

The way I'm trying to solve it is by defining a dictionary:

```
defaults = {None: None, '': None}

def foo(a):
    return defaults.get(a, func(a))

def foo_b(a):
    defaults_b = {'bar': 0, **defaults}
    return defaults_b.get(a, func(a))
```

When running the script:

```
foo_b(None)
```

It gets to the `get` method,
gets `None` back from `defaults` dict
and goes inside `func()` method with `None`
and I get errors cause `func()` method doesn't excepts `None`'s

What is the best practice to solve this issue with python?

Comment: @Barmar you're right, typo mistake

Comment: Python evaluates arguments before passing them to any function. So, before calling `defaults_b.get`, both `a` and `func(a)` are evaluated

Comment: Did you try just making a wrapper for `func` so that it *does* accept `None` and does something sensible with it?

Answer (score 1):

This can't work because all the arguments to a function are evaluated before the function is called. So when you write

```
defaults.get(a, func(a))
```

it first evaluates `a` and `func(a)`, and passes both results to `defaults.get()`. Since `func(a)` doesn't work for some values of `a`, you get an error before ever getting into `defaults.get()`.

The way to solve this in general is for the default to be a function, which will only be called when necessary. You'll need to write your own version of `dict.get()` that works this way.

```
def dict_get_f(d, key, default_fun):
    if key in d:
        return d[key]
    return default_fun()
```

You can then use it like this:

```
def foo(a):
    return dict_get_f(defaults, a, lambda: func(a))
```

Comment: You could also use `collections.defaultdict` to get this behaviour, rather than defining a new function.

Comment: @Oli Will `defaultdict` work with `{'bar': 0, **defaults}`?

Comment: Anyway, that sounds like an answer you could post.

Comment: Posted an answer with `defaultdict` plus some more alternatives that I thought of!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check in the function itself?

```
def func(t):
    if t is None:
        return None
    # go on with the code
```

Comment: I think the question implies that `func()` can't be changed. They're trying to come up with a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

### The Problem

As @Barmar pointed out in their answer, the problem is not the behaviour of `dict.get`, but the fact that all arguments are evaluated before the function is called, so `defaults.get(a, func(a))` calls `func(a)` before it calls `defaults.get` using that value.

### Solution 1: `collections.defaultdict`

An alternative way solving this is to use `collections.defaultdict`, which provides a way of calling a function when the value is not in the dictionary.

Since your dictionaries are small, copying them is low cost, so this solution does this.

```
from collections import defaultdict

defaults = {None: None, '': None}


def func(arg):
    """Some function that cannot be called with None"""
    if arg is None:
        raise ValueError()
    print(f'func called with {arg}')


def foo(a):
    return defaultdict(lambda: func(a), defaults)[a]


def foo_b(a):
    defaults_b = {'bar': 0, **defaults}
    return defaultdict(lambda: func(a), defaults_b)[a]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(foo(None))
    print(foo(''))
    print(foo(123))
    print(foo(123))
    print(foo_b(None))
    print(foo_b('bar'))
```

### Solution 2: functions everywhere!

Another approach you could take would be to make the `defaults` dictionary a dictionary of functions, and use a default value of `lambda: func(a)`, to avoid calling the function with `None`. So, `defaults.get(a, lambda: func(a))` will return a function that returns the correct value, which you can then call to get the value you want: `defaults.get(a, lambda: func(a))()`.

A full program:

```
defaults = {None: (lambda: None), '': (lambda: None)}

def func(arg):
    """Some function that cannot be called with None"""
    if arg is None:
        raise ValueError()
    print(f'func called with {arg}')


def foo(a):
    return defaults.get(a, lambda: func(a))()


def foo_b(a):
    defaults_b = {'bar': (lambda: 0), **defaults}
    return defaults_b.get(a, lambda: func(a))()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(foo(None))
    print(foo(''))
    print(foo(123))
    print(foo(123))
    print(foo_b(None))
    print(foo_b('bar'))
```

### Solution 3: flashy and somewhat obfuscated boolean operation short-circuiting

As a third option, you could use the behaviour of `and` in python, replying upon the fact that all default values you list are "falsy" ([What is Truthy and Falsy? How is it different from True and False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)). In python, `a and b` is short-circuiting, meaning that if `a` is `False` or falsy, then it already knows that `a and b` cannot be `True`, so it returns `a`, or if `a` is truthy then it returns `b`.

So, if `a` is `None`, then `defaults.get(a, True) and func(a)` is equal to `None and func(a)`. `None` is falsy, so `None and func(a)` is equal to `None`. If `a` is not in `defaults` then `defaults.get(a, True) and func(a)` is equal to `True and func(a)`, which is equal to `func(a)`, so the function gets called.

Note that this will not work if you use a truthy default value, e.g. if `defaults = {None: None, '': None, 'bar': 'something'}`, and it may be hard to understand for maintainability - I just thought I'd give another option.

```
defaults = {None: None, '': None}


def func(arg):
    """Some function that cannot be called with None"""
    if arg is None:
        raise ValueError()
    print(f'func called with {arg}')


def foo(a):
    return defaults.get(a, True) and func(a)


def foo_b(a):
    defaults_b = {'bar': 0, **defaults}
    return defaults_b.get(a, True) and func(a)
```